# Ansible Playbook and syntax issue with variables

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, syntax, yaml

I'm trying to execute the below playbook I wrote but it fails on some syntax errors.

I tried few things from the online doc but without sucess so far. The aim of these variable is to generate a random password to be used by the user module in a role.

```
 - hosts: all
   remote_user: root
   become : no
   vars:
      salt: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=10' chars=ascii_letters) }}"
      pasw: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=15') }}"
      hash: "{{ pasw }} | password_hash('sha512', {{ salt }}) "
   roles:
      - ansiuser
```

the error from ansible-playbook execution (it fails at role execution so I guess my variables aren't doing what I'm looking for: generating strings)

```
    TASK [ansiuser : Set the password fact for this host] ******************************************************************************************************************
    fatal: [192.168.11.100]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ pasw }} | password_hash('sha512', {{ salt }}) '. 
Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=10' chars=ascii_letters)  }}'. 

Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: template error while templating string: expected token ',', got 'chars'. String: {{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=10' chars=ascii_letters)  }}"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a simple typo.

```
      salt: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=10' chars=ascii_letters) }}"
```

You can see that the error complained about the literal text `chars` appearing unexpectedly. That's because you closed the quote early, where it was supposed to contain all of the options, i.e.:

```
      salt: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=10 chars=ascii_letters') }}"
```

Comment: oh … you'r perfectly right, that's so stupid of me … thanks a lot for your assistance there